# Display different data in collapsible panel body

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I am working on displaying data into multiple collapsible panel body dynamically to display individual data into each body on click but somehow on every click it sharing same data for each panels.

What I wanted to do is to display individual data for each item. Here is my sample code that I have written.

```
<span ng-repeat="t in tabledata">
                <div class="bs-example">
                    <div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
                        <div class="panel panel-primary">
                            <div class="panel-heading">
                                <h4 class="panel-title">
                                    <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#{{t.appSystemName}}">
                                        <table class="table borderless">
                                            <tr>
                                                <td>
                                                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"
                                                        ng-click="getDataForProdQa(t.appSystemName)"
                                                        ng-model="plus">
                                                    </span>
                                                </td>
                                                <td>{{t.dbName}}</td>
                                                <td>{{t.appSystemName}}</td>
                                                <td>{{t.Id}}</td>
                                                <td>{{t.frequency}}</td>
                                                <td>{{t.timeStamp}}</td>
                                            </tr>
                                        </table>
                                    </a>
                                </h4>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div id="{{t.appSystemName}}" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                            <div class="panel-body">
                                <table class="table table-responsive" >
                                    <tr ng-repeat="i in innertabledata">
                                        <td>{{i.dbName}}</td>
                                        <td ng-model="check">{{i.appSystemName}}</td>
                                        <td>{{i.Id}}</td>
                                        <td>{{i.frequency}}</td>
                                        <td>{{i.timeStamp}}</td>
                                    </tr>

                                </table>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </span>
```

Looking some assistance to fix this issue

Comment: Could you create a plunker with the bare minimum? It would be easier for us to help you

Comment: I don't know if I can create it.

Comment: You need to show minimal viable code or more, preferably with plunker or something. This is only an HTML template we have no idea if the problem is here, it might be something as simple as wrong object name or property name.

Answer (score 0):

just try to make the id="accordion" dynamic as it is under ng-repeat and everytime same id is duplicated.So make dynamic id like id="accordion{{$index}}" and also the data-parent make it dynamic.Hope this helps.
Thanks